# svg animation is not working on line path

Tags: javascript, svg, svg-animate

i am trying to move a flight image on a line drawn using SVG. i don't have any knowledge in SVG i found an example to that but its not working. please find the code below.

```
<div class="screenwidth">
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 width="1351.000000pt" height="1721.000000pt" viewBox="0 0 1351.000000 1721.000000"
 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">


<g transform="translate(0.000000,1721.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
fill="#000000" stroke="#000000">

<path id="motionPath" d="M9266 15119 c-22 -5 -46 -14 -53 -21 -8 -6 -26 -12 -41 -13 -27 -2
-55 -15 -117 -55 -16 -10 -51 -30 -77 -44 l-48 -26 -47 21 c-27 12 -59 27 -73
34 -57 30 -251 47 -265 25 -4 -6 -21 -8 -40 -4 -42 8 -200 -30 -238 -58 -16
-11 -40 -22 -55 -24 -74 -13 -381 -180 -417 -228 -12 -15 -90 -64 -118 -73
-21 -7 -19 -32 4 -46 13 -8 26 -2 60 25 136 111 423 270 569 316 163 52 311
65 428 37 50 -12 133 -45 150 -60 2 -2 -18 -22 -45 -46 -262 -233 -476 -572
-498 -788 -2 -28 -7 -62 -11 -75 -9 -39 14 -164 42 -223 36 -75 117 -152 206
-196 294 -145 556 -135 802 30 122 83 238 235 268 351 14 56 -8 118 -108 307
-148 278 -289 443 -536 627 l-23 17 25 21 c42 35 202 108 264 120 181 37 648
-86 931 -244 166 -93 281 -188 320 -266 32 -63 60 -157 81 -275 28 -155 27
-537 -3 -700 -43 -233 -118 -428 -234 -600 -54 -81 -74 -100 -182 -182 -269
-200 -562 -353 -677 -353 -22 0 -93 -18 -157 -41 -308 -107 -388 -133 -517
-169 -377 -108 -878 -166 -1201 -140 -71 5 -173 12 -225 15 -120 7 -205 18
-460 60 -426 71 -827 114 -1580 170 -1370 101 -1791 166 -2345 360 -689 242
-1314 255 -1749 38 -119 -59 -165 -92 -268 -191 -120 -115 -206 -251 -261
-412 -65 -187 -73 -276 -93 -925 -27 -903 -10 -1143 106 -1555 87 -304 130
-393 244 -496 74 -68 208 -134 326 -163 113 -27 306 -45 405 -37 44 3 113 8
154 11 41 3 83 7 93 11 10 3 18 1 18 -5 0 -16 37 -13 43 3 3 7 23 16 44 19 21
3 49 8 63 12 14 3 41 8 60 11 19 3 53 10 75 16 22 5 41 10 42 10 20 -1 168 49
273 92 254 104 434 140 705 140 224 0 272 -7 595 -84 505 -121 747 -158 995
-155 256 3 408 45 542 148 101 77 130 113 398 482 39 53 71 100 73 105 2 5 20
27 40 48 20 22 73 79 117 127 195 216 440 376 780 510 174 69 361 161 515 255
158 96 426 229 735 365 121 53 234 104 250 112 138 68 454 163 611 184 112 15
329 6 409 -16 241 -67 415 -244 494 -499 27 -88 41 -301 30 -476 -7 -126 -26
-250 -38 -250 -3 0 -19 19 -36 43 -90 127 -397 496 -445 534 -72 57 -190 117
-266 137 -80 21 -215 21 -285 0 -209 -62 -373 -234 -540 -564 -103 -206 -157
-396 -166 -590 -9 -193 40 -347 135 -431 75 -66 166 -74 350 -33 110 25 316
91 417 134 28 11 68 29 90 38 104 44 320 161 420 227 151 100 252 201 305 307
23 45 42 84 44 85 4 5 70 -95 95 -144 66 -131 340 -340 556 -424 56 -22 103
-33 158 -37 105 -6 125 6 304 179 168 162 270 240 403 309 303 155 588 182
947 90 370 -95 636 -275 715 -485 33 -87 31 -224 -4 -316 -87 -223 -245 -389
-719 -755 -682 -528 -1223 -921 -1625 -1181 l-110 -72 -170 -25 c-382 -56
-742 -92 -1056 -105 -274 -12 -462 -1 -611 36 -131 32 -253 35 -407 8 -145
-25 -143 -24 -340 -60 -881 -161 -1648 -164 -2665 -9 -803 121 -972 145 -1505
211 -223 27 -257 31 -370 38 -41 3 -124 10 -185 16 -60 6 -144 13 -185 15 -41
2 -164 8 -273 14 -398 20 -1002 8 -1156 -25 -295 -62 -690 -294 -921 -541
-151 -162 -265 -359 -317 -549 -27 -99 -28 -103 -28 -410 1 -238 5 -338 18
-431 55 -388 150 -667 308 -905 100 -150 284 -328 429 -417 60 -36 236 -121
304 -147 163 -61 415 -113 659 -135 121 -11 661 -14 771 -5 235 20 696 37 866
32 354 -10 398 -28 633 -261 92 -91 171 -166 175 -166 5 0 32 -23 62 -50 30
-28 59 -50 66 -50 7 0 14 -6 17 -14 7 -17 242 -194 347 -261 135 -87 284 -151
400 -174 145 -28 292 -48 440 -60 150 -13 544 -7 655 8 399 57 684 173 916
373 72 62 189 194 189 214 0 7 7 14 15 18 8 3 15 9 15 13 0 12 107 122 175
180 191 162 475 293 805 372 319 77 709 100 933 56 40 -7 117 -34 172 -58 628
-281 1009 -539 1120 -757 80 -157 40 -448 -112 -835 -113 -287 -259 -562 -355
-670 -50 -56 -182 -150 -253 -180 -277 -118 -667 -164 -1156 -136 -285 16
-422 43 -551 107 -108 54 -157 114 -179 214 -13 59 -35 67 -45 15 -10 -57 19
-116 94 -194 56 -57 80 -72 147 -99 157 -62 397 -99 578 -89 93 6 107 5 107
-9 0 -14 12 -15 93 -9 50 4 97 12 104 17 7 6 47 7 101 3 61 -5 91 -4 96 4 5 7
28 8 67 4 106 -11 400 54 535 118 34 16 65 29 70 29 18 0 136 85 155 111 11
16 26 29 34 29 12 0 52 42 104 110 42 55 166 299 247 485 9 22 21 48 25 57 55
112 148 412 168 538 4 30 7 118 6 195 -2 123 -5 146 -24 180 -70 130 -104 175
-128 175 -7 0 -18 11 -23 24 -9 24 -68 76 -87 76 -6 0 -18 11 -27 25 -15 23
-206 158 -244 172 -9 4 -37 21 -62 38 -43 31 -226 126 -395 206 -44 21 -117
56 -163 78 -46 23 -90 41 -98 41 -8 0 -27 8 -41 17 -17 11 -48 18 -88 19 -34
1 -68 4 -74 9 -7 4 -43 4 -82 0 -48 -5 -69 -4 -69 4 0 6 -16 11 -35 11 -19 0
-35 -5 -35 -11 0 -7 -30 -8 -99 -4 -64 5 -101 4 -105 -3 -3 -6 -23 -8 -45 -5
-23 3 -41 1 -45 -6 -4 -6 -18 -8 -32 -5 -13 3 -32 3 -41 -1 -10 -4 -43 -9 -73
-10 -80 -5 -338 -67 -465 -114 -135 -49 -408 -186 -484 -243 -60 -44 -188
-169 -208 -203 -7 -11 -15 -27 -19 -35 -4 -8 -13 -19 -21 -23 -7 -4 -13 -12
-13 -17 0 -8 -228 -240 -236 -240 -1 0 -39 -25 -83 -56 -162 -111 -428 -217
-639 -255 -40 -7 -75 -16 -78 -20 -3 -5 -18 -6 -33 -3 -16 3 -32 1 -35 -5 -4
-6 -24 -8 -51 -4 -25 3 -50 1 -57 -4 -16 -12 -158 -4 -158 8 0 12 -183 12
-195 0 -11 -11 -123 -17 -145 -8 -25 9 -261 30 -267 23 -3 -3 -12 -1 -20 5 -7
6 -23 9 -35 6 -12 -4 -28 -1 -35 5 -7 5 -32 12 -55 13 -24 2 -51 6 -61 10 -10
4 -21 5 -24 1 -3 -3 -11 -2 -17 2 -16 12 -126 51 -161 57 -16 2 -41 14 -55 25
-14 11 -59 43 -100 70 -41 27 -116 80 -166 117 -50 37 -104 74 -120 82 -16 9
-43 26 -61 39 -17 12 -33 22 -35 22 -2 0 -28 22 -58 50 -30 27 -58 50 -62 50
-4 0 -25 19 -45 43 -86 96 -177 187 -190 187 -7 0 -13 6 -13 13 0 24 -104 114
-181 156 -50 28 -234 64 -286 57 -23 -3 -45 -1 -48 4 -8 12 -352 13 -359 1 -3
-4 -48 -6 -100 -3 -52 2 -103 1 -113 -3 -10 -4 -48 -6 -85 -5 -37 1 -73 -2
-80 -6 -7 -5 -47 -7 -89 -5 -42 1 -79 -2 -83 -7 -3 -5 -53 -7 -121 -4 -77 3
-119 1 -128 -6 -16 -14 -306 -16 -322 -2 -5 4 -84 11 -175 15 -222 9 -223 9
-236 17 -6 4 -44 12 -85 19 -112 16 -295 64 -398 104 -51 19 -99 35 -107 35
-19 0 -91 39 -116 63 -10 9 -24 17 -31 17 -7 0 -56 34 -108 76 -52 41 -101 78
-109 81 -19 7 -130 115 -130 126 0 4 -25 41 -55 82 -65 89 -130 206 -194 354
-27 61 -54 117 -60 125 -7 8 -14 27 -16 43 -2 15 -4 28 -5 28 -1 0 -3 11 -5
25 -9 78 -78 487 -84 500 -4 8 -6 65 -3 126 3 76 1 113 -7 118 -14 9 -15 113
0 121 6 4 10 45 9 103 -1 54 1 104 5 113 3 10 5 23 4 30 -1 8 0 21 3 29 3 8
16 47 28 85 79 250 235 466 476 659 225 180 539 332 754 366 41 7 82 14 90 17
8 3 50 4 92 3 43 -1 82 2 88 5 11 7 737 8 748 1 6 -4 275 -16 452 -21 30 -1
63 -5 73 -9 10 -5 38 -6 62 -3 26 4 47 2 50 -4 4 -5 25 -9 48 -9 23 1 71 -1
107 -5 36 -3 79 -8 96 -9 17 -2 37 -6 43 -10 6 -4 28 -7 49 -5 20 1 45 -2 55
-6 10 -4 35 -5 57 -1 24 4 41 2 46 -5 4 -7 20 -9 40 -6 19 3 36 1 40 -4 3 -6
18 -9 32 -8 15 1 35 -2 45 -6 9 -4 29 -5 42 -2 14 2 28 0 31 -5 3 -5 20 -8 38
-7 17 1 39 -2 49 -6 9 -4 29 -5 42 -2 14 2 28 0 31 -5 3 -5 20 -8 38 -7 17 1
39 -2 49 -6 9 -4 28 -4 41 -1 14 3 28 1 31 -5 4 -5 19 -9 33 -8 15 1 34 -1 42
-4 28 -11 335 -58 400 -62 36 -2 73 -7 83 -10 9 -4 24 -4 33 -1 9 4 22 2 28
-2 16 -13 182 -44 251 -47 33 -2 68 -6 78 -10 9 -4 24 -4 33 -1 9 4 23 1 30
-5 8 -6 23 -9 34 -6 11 3 22 2 25 -3 6 -10 201 -34 214 -26 5 4 13 1 16 -5 4
-5 24 -9 44 -8 20 2 42 0 48 -4 7 -4 52 -10 101 -12 49 -2 96 -7 106 -11 10
-4 46 -4 81 -1 42 4 67 2 71 -5 4 -7 31 -9 75 -5 45 4 71 2 75 -5 5 -8 50 -9
145 -4 89 4 140 3 144 -4 7 -12 235 -14 235 -2 0 4 90 7 200 7 130 0 203 4
210 11 6 6 31 9 59 6 28 -2 51 0 55 6 4 6 21 8 41 5 19 -3 42 -2 52 2 10 5 26
7 36 6 24 -3 181 16 287 35 47 8 137 24 200 35 162 29 213 40 228 52 6 5 12 6
12 2 0 -4 7 -2 15 5 8 6 23 9 34 5 12 -3 26 -3 32 1 6 3 42 7 80 9 37 1 74 7
82 13 18 15 182 -3 260 -29 31 -11 101 -23 155 -28 132 -12 540 -12 547 0 4 5
35 6 74 3 46 -5 70 -3 75 4 5 8 27 9 66 5 32 -3 67 -2 77 2 21 8 61 12 190 18
50 3 97 9 105 13 7 5 25 7 40 5 14 -1 29 2 32 8 4 5 22 7 41 4 32 -5 179 13
198 24 4 2 33 6 65 7 32 1 64 6 71 10 7 5 42 10 78 12 39 3 75 12 91 23 15 10
61 39 102 66 41 27 93 61 115 77 22 16 72 50 110 75 125 83 335 236 335 245 0
4 6 8 14 8 7 0 24 10 38 23 13 12 36 28 50 36 14 7 40 26 58 42 17 16 33 29
36 29 24 0 374 263 374 281 0 5 7 9 15 9 9 0 18 7 21 15 4 8 11 15 17 15 15 0
237 169 237 181 0 5 7 9 15 9 9 0 18 7 21 15 4 8 12 15 20 15 8 0 19 9 26 20
7 11 19 20 26 20 7 0 15 7 18 15 4 8 10 15 15 15 20 0 329 241 365 285 21 25
44 45 51 45 7 0 22 14 35 30 12 17 27 30 33 30 12 0 85 72 85 84 0 4 11 17 25
28 14 11 25 26 25 34 0 8 4 14 10 14 5 0 16 15 24 33 8 17 30 49 50 69 41 45
96 154 100 201 2 19 6 39 10 46 15 24 18 129 6 182 -16 73 -76 196 -100 209
-11 6 -20 15 -20 21 0 5 -28 38 -63 72 -63 63 -114 97 -287 190 -110 60 -463
156 -527 144 -13 -2 -26 -1 -28 3 -6 10 -256 7 -272 -3 -6 -4 -18 -4 -27 -1
-8 3 -21 2 -28 -2 -7 -5 -23 -7 -35 -6 -54 7 -333 -92 -398 -142 -16 -13 -40
-26 -53 -30 -40 -13 -177 -123 -236 -190 -31 -36 -69 -71 -84 -78 -14 -7 -32
-23 -38 -36 -16 -32 -65 -82 -81 -82 -7 0 -20 -11 -29 -25 -10 -15 -26 -25
-40 -25 -13 0 -33 -5 -44 -12 -14 -9 -25 -9 -42 -1 -31 15 -117 35 -126 29 -4
-3 -28 9 -52 26 -25 16 -74 45 -110 63 -36 18 -87 49 -115 69 -27 20 -53 36
-56 36 -7 0 -38 28 -132 119 -26 25 -57 64 -69 86 -11 22 -45 76 -76 120 l-55
79 21 126 c17 97 22 165 21 305 0 99 -3 184 -6 188 -3 5 -7 37 -8 71 -4 89
-73 272 -131 348 -16 21 -37 49 -47 63 -10 14 -24 25 -31 25 -8 0 -30 20 -50
44 -21 27 -59 56 -91 72 -31 14 -57 30 -60 34 -7 12 -125 52 -163 55 -21 2
-45 6 -54 10 -10 4 -25 5 -33 2 -8 -4 -17 -2 -20 3 -9 15 -202 12 -325 -5
-105 -15 -221 -45 -265 -68 -11 -6 -32 -11 -46 -12 -14 -1 -41 -9 -60 -18 -19
-8 -48 -19 -64 -25 -17 -5 -48 -21 -69 -36 -21 -14 -51 -26 -66 -26 -15 0 -30
-3 -34 -7 -4 -4 -24 -13 -44 -19 -64 -20 -332 -142 -394 -179 -33 -19 -67 -35
-77 -35 -22 0 -194 -83 -229 -110 -13 -11 -31 -20 -39 -20 -15 0 -166 -84
-198 -110 -11 -9 -49 -31 -85 -50 -36 -18 -72 -38 -80 -44 -8 -7 -27 -17 -42
-24 -16 -6 -28 -16 -28 -22 0 -5 -9 -10 -20 -10 -11 0 -53 -15 -93 -34 -40
-18 -99 -43 -132 -55 -33 -12 -73 -31 -88 -42 -16 -12 -34 -22 -40 -23 -61
-13 -207 -80 -302 -139 -156 -97 -425 -327 -425 -364 0 -7 -5 -13 -10 -13 -6
0 -14 -8 -17 -17 -4 -10 -21 -36 -40 -59 -18 -23 -33 -45 -33 -50 0 -5 -13
-18 -30 -27 -16 -10 -30 -22 -30 -27 0 -4 -12 -21 -28 -38 -15 -16 -38 -50
-51 -76 -13 -25 -28 -46 -33 -46 -5 0 -11 -7 -15 -16 -3 -9 -17 -28 -29 -42
-13 -14 -24 -31 -24 -37 0 -7 -7 -15 -15 -19 -8 -3 -15 -12 -15 -21 0 -8 -4
-15 -9 -15 -10 0 -101 -114 -101 -127 0 -14 -75 -84 -82 -77 -4 3 -14 -6 -23
-20 -10 -14 -23 -26 -30 -26 -7 0 -42 -13 -77 -29 -35 -16 -91 -36 -124 -45
-32 -9 -66 -20 -74 -23 -8 -3 -27 -5 -42 -4 -15 1 -32 -1 -39 -4 -9 -6 -286
-10 -299 -4 -3 1 -25 3 -50 4 -25 1 -52 5 -60 8 -29 12 -381 68 -390 62 -5 -3
-12 -1 -15 5 -4 6 -14 10 -23 9 -10 -1 -24 1 -32 4 -54 23 -537 130 -640 142
-143 17 -286 20 -295 5 -3 -5 -33 -7 -68 -4 -95 8 -450 -69 -491 -107 -6 -5
-19 -9 -30 -9 -12 0 -66 -20 -120 -45 -55 -25 -107 -45 -116 -45 -8 0 -32 -8
-52 -19 -21 -10 -48 -16 -63 -14 -14 3 -36 -2 -50 -11 -14 -9 -25 -14 -25 -10
0 4 -7 1 -15 -6 -8 -7 -21 -10 -30 -7 -8 4 -17 1 -21 -4 -3 -6 -17 -8 -31 -4
-14 3 -31 1 -39 -5 -7 -7 -17 -9 -22 -6 -6 3 -15 -1 -22 -9 -9 -11 -18 -12
-38 -4 -29 11 -150 3 -167 -12 -6 -4 -82 -4 -170 2 -88 5 -168 8 -179 5 -10
-3 -26 -1 -35 4 -9 4 -67 23 -130 41 -79 23 -135 47 -186 78 -75 47 -164 124
-189 164 -33 52 -159 447 -172 539 -6 41 -30 147 -41 178 -3 8 -6 40 -7 70 -3
68 -16 210 -22 229 -8 24 -7 627 0 640 4 6 6 72 5 146 -1 75 1 138 5 142 4 4
6 83 6 176 -1 93 1 171 4 174 3 4 6 48 6 99 0 58 10 145 26 231 14 76 27 149
28 163 2 14 10 37 18 50 8 14 35 63 60 110 24 47 62 111 84 144 21 32 45 69
52 83 8 13 24 28 36 33 12 4 39 27 60 51 40 44 63 59 206 132 103 54 199 89
305 112 44 10 84 20 88 22 4 3 45 7 90 10 44 2 86 7 92 11 29 18 455 -14 634
-49 103 -19 438 -111 471 -129 39 -21 388 -121 555 -159 295 -67 825 -145 870
-127 8 3 17 1 21 -5 3 -6 25 -9 48 -8 22 1 48 -1 56 -4 26 -9 349 -37 483 -42
70 -2 132 -7 137 -10 5 -3 63 -8 129 -10 66 -3 127 -8 136 -11 9 -4 45 -4 80
-1 40 4 67 2 71 -4 3 -6 25 -9 48 -8 22 1 48 -1 56 -4 8 -3 172 -19 364 -37
360 -32 677 -72 923 -116 78 -13 169 -26 202 -29 33 -2 65 -6 71 -10 6 -4 23
-5 38 -4 15 1 35 -2 45 -6 9 -4 37 -4 61 -1 28 4 47 3 51 -4 3 -6 32 -10 63
-10 31 0 166 -1 300 -4 141 -2 244 0 248 5 3 5 27 7 54 3 27 -4 57 -3 67 1 10
4 56 9 103 11 98 4 362 51 507 89 236 64 423 123 472 150 59 31 240 83 315 90
71 6 93 14 215 75 141 72 261 145 261 160 0 5 25 21 56 36 31 15 64 34 74 43
9 9 32 25 51 35 19 10 45 29 59 41 14 12 38 30 53 40 56 36 230 331 240 406 1
15 8 33 14 40 23 29 73 199 77 262 2 37 7 71 10 76 3 5 6 24 6 43 1 58 7 112
15 131 12 28 1 383 -13 399 -6 8 -9 24 -5 36 3 12 0 28 -6 36 -6 7 -9 20 -6
28 8 21 -22 164 -51 241 -20 53 -42 86 -91 138 -36 37 -73 71 -84 74 -11 4
-31 17 -46 31 -35 32 -172 113 -203 120 -14 3 -34 10 -45 17 -86 49 -134 70
-230 102 -175 58 -350 98 -443 100 -45 1 -85 5 -89 8 -8 9 -49 7 -97 -4z
m-288 -240 c17 -6 33 -17 36 -25 3 -8 11 -14 18 -14 7 0 19 -9 26 -20 7 -11
16 -20 20 -20 11 0 222 -211 222 -221 0 -6 7 -12 15 -15 8 -4 15 -10 15 -15 0
-13 115 -185 152 -227 15 -18 28 -41 28 -51 0 -20 86 -207 99 -216 8 -4 2 -45
-17 -125 -5 -19 -23 -51 -41 -71 -18 -20 -40 -51 -49 -70 -9 -19 -29 -40 -44
-47 -15 -7 -36 -24 -46 -37 -11 -14 -25 -25 -30 -25 -6 0 -15 -6 -19 -14 -8
-15 -213 -106 -238 -106 -8 0 -16 -4 -20 -10 -3 -5 -12 -7 -20 -3 -8 3 -23 2
-32 -2 -26 -11 -146 -12 -160 -2 -7 5 -24 6 -37 3 -14 -3 -28 -1 -31 4 -4 6
-14 10 -23 9 -10 -1 -19 0 -22 1 -3 1 -18 3 -34 5 -17 2 -42 13 -57 25 -16 11
-37 20 -47 20 -10 0 -33 13 -50 28 -17 16 -44 35 -59 43 -59 30 -124 136 -141
229 -20 105 -23 140 -11 140 6 0 9 12 8 28 -2 15 2 36 8 47 6 11 14 36 18 55
10 46 95 226 132 282 17 24 41 65 54 92 13 27 43 64 66 84 24 19 43 38 43 43
0 13 157 169 169 169 6 0 16 9 23 20 14 23 31 25 76 9z m7 -4049 c3 -5 21 -10
38 -10 52 0 187 -53 258 -101 73 -49 159 -124 159 -139 0 -5 9 -15 20 -22 11
-7 20 -18 20 -24 0 -7 20 -33 45 -58 25 -26 45 -51 45 -56 0 -15 118 -158 145
-176 14 -9 25 -21 25 -26 0 -5 16 -25 35 -45 59 -60 61 -86 20 -186 -20 -47
-43 -91 -51 -98 -8 -6 -14 -16 -14 -21 0 -12 -9 -21 -106 -100 -45 -36 -111
-83 -145 -103 -35 -21 -80 -50 -100 -66 -20 -16 -42 -29 -48 -29 -6 0 -20 -9
-30 -19 -26 -26 -55 -41 -78 -41 -11 0 -45 -16 -77 -35 -32 -19 -65 -35 -72
-35 -8 0 -22 -4 -32 -9 -36 -20 -253 -92 -377 -127 -71 -19 -137 -38 -145 -41
-29 -10 -160 -3 -192 10 -43 18 -117 93 -125 126 -3 14 -10 32 -16 39 -13 16
-14 22 -25 202 -5 87 -5 150 0 157 5 6 8 20 7 30 -1 10 0 25 3 33 3 8 27 80
53 160 48 147 124 302 233 478 29 46 52 86 52 90 0 6 101 102 108 102 2 0 21
13 41 29 20 15 56 38 81 51 25 12 51 27 58 33 7 6 41 12 75 14 34 3 66 9 72
14 12 12 32 12 40 -1z"/>


  <path d="M 439.48098,95.969555 L 393.34268,142.46481 L 305.91233,133.41187 L 324.72376,114.58551 L 308.61525,98.464215 L 276.15845,130.94677 L 185.25346,123.08136 L 201.15145,107.27643 L 186.46085,92.574165 L 158.32,120.73735 L 45.386032,112.12042 L 15.000017,131.66667 L 221.20641,192.48691 L 298.26133,237.01135 L 191.91028,345.62828 L 152.82697,408.6082 L 41.549634,393.05411 L 21.037984,413.58203 L 109.25334,470.93369 L 166.38515,558.95725 L 186.8968,538.42933 L 171.35503,427.06371 L 234.28504,387.94939 L 342.81586,281.51396 L 387.305,358.63003 L 448.07703,565.00001 L 467.60778,534.58989 L 458.99769,421.56633 L 487.16033,393.38134 L 473.14247,379.35235 L 456.6139,395.97492 L 448.79636,303.63439 L 481.25315,271.15184 L 465.14464,255.03055 L 446.33321,273.8569 L 436.04766,185.1164 L 482.35108,138.7864 C 501.1942,119.92833 560.62425,61.834815 564.99998,14.999985 C 515.28999,23.707295 476.1521,61.495405 439.48098,95.969555 z "
     style="opacity:1;color:#0099ff;fill:#0099ff;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none;marker:none;visibility:visible;display:inline;overflow:visible" />
</g>

  <animateMotion 
           xlink:href="#plane"
           dur="10s" 
           repeatCount="1" 
           rotate="auto" 
           fill="freeze"
    <mpath xlink:href="#motionPath" />
  </animateMotion>
</svg>
</div>
```

SVG line image is created in Photoshop and then its was converted to SVG path. i thing its not the problem.

Please comment if you have any doubts. thank you

Comment: So which tool do you use to render the SVG where you expect that `animateMotion` to work? It has never been supported well and http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-smil says its support will be removed from Chrome and Edge

Comment: i am trying on html page checking in chrome

Comment: @MartinHonnen. `<animateMotion>` has never been supported by IE/Edge, but it is well supported in other browsers.  It will not be removed from Chrome any time soon.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau, sorry about that wrong statement regarding Edge, I am sure I wanted to simply repeat that note from caniuse regarding Chrome and Opera but somehow I ended up writing Edge instead of Opera. As for your statement on `animateMotion` not being removed from Chrome any time soon, is that specific to `animateMotion` or the SMIL based SVG animation in general? Hmm, I found https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/blink-dev/5o0yiO440LM/YGEJBsjUAwAJ so it seems that warning on caniuse is indeed not meant to be relevant.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Chrome initially announced that it was deprecating/removing SMIL support, but as you discovered, they changed their mind based on pushback from the community.

Comment: There is no element in your markup with id="plane" so the animateMotion doesn't seem to point to anything,.